# Twimlets voice mail is cut off

Tags: c#, twilio

I want to deliver voice message using Twilio. I also use text to voice twimlets as well. Here is the code

```
TwilioClient.Init(accountSid, authToken);
string responseurl = "http://twimlets.com/echo?Twiml=%3CResponse%3E%0A%3CSay%3EDear%20John%20Smith%3C%2FSay%3E%0A%3CSay%3E%0AThis%20is%20a%20test%20for%20happy%20programing%20IVR.%20Why%20this%20is%20so%20hard%3F%3F%0A%3C%2FSay%3E%0A%3CPlay%3E%0Ahttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.pacdv.com%2Fsounds%2Fpeople_sound_effects%2Fapplause-4.mp3%0A%3C%2FPlay%3E%0A%3CSay%3EGood%20Bye%3C%2FSay%3E%0A%3C%2FResponse%3E&";

var call = CallResource.Create(to,from,url: new Uri(responseurl));




<Response>
<Say>Dear John Smith</Say>
<Say>
This is a test for happy programing IVR. Why this is so hard??
</Say>
<Play>
http://www.pacdv.com/sounds/people_sound_effects/applause-4.mp3
</Play>
<Say>Good Bye</Say>
</Response>
```

Here is the problem, When I pick up the call, I will hear all voicemail played.  When it goes to the voicemail, It will cut the first 7 seconds recording off. 
Anyone knows how to solve this problem?
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

The issue is that when your voicemail answers the phone it starts by reading its own message. At the same time, Twilio is reading the message out too, so when the voicemail starts recording the message is halfway through.

There are two ways you can get around this. Either you build a loop into your message to ensure that it all gets recorded. Or you can use [Twilio's Answer Machine Detection](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/voice/answering-machine-detection) to only start the message when it is sure that a human or machine has answered.

To use the AMD you need to pass another parameter when you create the call:

```
var call = CallResource.Create(
  to, from,
  url: new Uri(responseurl)
  machineDetection: "DetectMessageEnd"
);
```

`machineDetection` can be either "Enable" or "DetectMessageEnd". "Enable" will call your webhook URL as soon as Twilio knows if it is human or machine, "DetectMessageEnd" will wait if it is a machine until the voicemail's message has ended, allowing you to play your message and have it fully recorded.

When Twilio requests your webhook URL, it will have an extra parameter too, [`AnsweredBy`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/voice/answering-machine-detection#webhook-parameters). You can use this to decide what course to take depending on whether a human or machine answered.

Let me know if this helps at all.